# Scheduling task with windows scheduler to run .jar file along with .ini configuration file

Tags: java, jar

I am able to  run .jar using windows task scheduler but what do I have to do if I have a configuration file(.ini) in project root folder and my .jar file in project distribution folder.

In my 1st sample program without configuration file, I am executing the .jar file alone by adding -jar PathTo .jar File in "Add Argumnets (optional)" pane, the program runs fine.

But in another program with configuration file, if I execute with the same command as above, nothing gets executed. And I am assuming this happens because the argument points to distribution folder and the configuration file is in the root folder.

Any ideas/help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the following file structure (and if I didn't misunderstand your description):

```
rootPath/
  +-- ConfigFile.ini
  +-- distFolder/
        +-- YourApp.jar
```

You should set task parameters like this:

> **Action:** Start a program
>   **Program/script:** "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe"
>   **Add arguments (optional):** -jar "rootPath\distFolder\YourApp.jar"
>   **Start in (optional):** rootPath

By this way, Windows scheduler should init your java application in `rootPath` directory and it shouldn't have problems to load `ConfigFile.ini`

*Note:* `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe` is my java path, just use yours of course. Also note is necessary use `javaw.exe`. Finally at `Start in` section, `rootPath` doesn't be quoted.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Though I used java.exe not javaw.exe because from what I read javaw.exe is meant for UI .

Comment: You're wellcome! :) Yes you're totally right about that. But I read in some other question that Window scheduler doesn't work with `java.exe` but it does with `javaw.exe`. I made a simple test and it's true, so `javaw.exe` it is. If it worked for you, please accept the answer so people finding for a similar problem can identify this as useful.